# How to embed eosio nonce action in transaction to get over Error 3030011: duplicate transaction?

Tags: transactions

```
Reading WAST/WASM from ______ wast...
Assembling WASM...
Publishing contract...
Error 3030011: duplicate transaction
You can try embedding eosio nonce action inside your transaction to ensure uniqueness.
Error Details:
Transaction is not unique
```

It is from [help_text.cpp in programs cleos](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/71ddb46cc76e33abdb1e6cd82f725fb28989d574/programs/cleos/help_text.cpp#L111)

1. What is eosio nonce?
2. How to embed it inside a transaction?

Comment: Text should not be pasted as image. Rather, paste it as a code block: then it can be readily copied for searching or other purposes.

Comment: Something seems funny about that screenshot. Is this from `cleos set contract`? If so you'd have to send the same code twice within .5s to get that error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the -f option in cleos

This option will instruct cleos to include a nonce action in the transaction you are creating, that will make the tx unique.

-f,--force-unique
force the transaction to be unique. this will consume extra bandwidth and remove any protections against accidently issuing the same transaction multiple times